# Problem playing audio after pausing with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone, uikit, avaudioplayer

I have an issue with my AVAudioPlayer in which if it is paused, I cannot get it to play again.  Calling [audioPlayer play] after it is paused returns NO rather than the usual YES.
Any idea what could have caused this?

Someone else has this same issue as well:

http://www.iphonedevforums.com/forum/sdk-coding-help/750-avaudioplayer-doesnt-start-back-up-after-interruption.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this same problem when setting `currentTime` before invoking the play method.  Moving the property set of `currentTime` to after invoking play method allowed `AVAudioPlayer` to return `YES` instead of `NO`.  I'm not sure why this is, hope it helps.

Edit: after further consultation with this issue, calling stop then play seems to work more consistently and thus allows `currentTime` setting before the play method.  You may want to call `prepareToPlay` just after your stop though to queue it up again for play when you're ready to resume.

Comment: Thankyou, I was having the same problem, but using MonoTouch, and your solution fixed it for me :)

Comment: @NeilDurant : could you pls post any sample code because even im using monotouch and facing the same problem.